# 'ScrollBar' is an ambiguous reference between 'System.Windows.Forms.ScrollBar' and 'Arction.LightningChartUltimate.ScrollBar'

Tags: c#

As mentioned in the title, I am having the problem of ambiguous reference between two using directive.

One is the `System.Windows.Forms`:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Another one is from a custom library, Arction API:

```
using Arction.LightningChartUltimate;
```

I would like to use the scroll bar class available in Arction instead of the standard window one.

So, how could I disable to use of scroll bar class in Windows.Form to resolve the ambiguous reference problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to use the fully qualified name `Arction.LightningChartUltimate.ScrollBar`.

Alternative you can create a namespace alias: `using arc = Arction.LightningChartUltimate` and then use `arc.ScrollBar` in your code or a type alias `using arcScrollBar = Arction.LightningChartUltimate.ScrollBar`  and then use `acrScrollBar` in your code.

**Update**: you can actually "override" a specific typename with a typealias: `using ScrollBar = Arction.LightningChartUltimate.Scrollbar;` actually makes all further references to `ScrollBar` refer to the on in the Action namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following `using` directive:

```
using ScrollBar = Arction.LightningChartUltimate.Scrollbar;
```

Then, when you refer to `ScrollBar` in your code, it will be `Arction.LightningChartUltimate.ScrollBar`

Comment: Also, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115606/error-on-timer-is-an-ambiguous-reference-between-system-windows-forms-timer